Gnucash: Delete or invalidate invoice
I have an invoice that will never be rendered to the customer. It was pretty wrong, and a new invoice was generated.  How can I invalidate or remove it? There's no concern about data integrity. I'm the only user and this is for a small proprietorship.

This is an FAQ.

GnuCash does not support deleting or invalidating invoices. The recommended process is to wait until another invoice is required then change the details to what is required for the new invoice.
